# What is the procedure for an air traffic controller after a major crash or incident occurs on their watch?

Tags: air-traffic-control, ntsb

How will an air traffic controller will be treated right after a major incident?

Comment: I'm not sure if its accurate, but maybe you should watch the moving "Pushing Tin." Its all about that.

Comment: [Peter Nielsen was murdered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlingen_mid-air_collision) by the man who lost his wife and two children in the crash. Really this is kind of broad, because it depends on the circumstances. Anything can happen from nothing, to psychological counseling, to remedial training, to prison depending on the cause of the accident and the controllers involvement in that accident. Sometimes they are immediately suspended, quarantined, and interrogated, possibly within hours of the accident.

Comment: @Devil07 Pushing Tin is a horribly inaccurate movie that does not depict reality in any way

Comment: The usual [advice from the doctor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uepFO4psgKE) seems appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Most units today will have some sort of CISM procedure.

> Critical Incident Stress Management (CISM) is the structured assistance for a normal reaction to an abnormal event.
>
> CISM methods are secondary preventive measures which consist of discussions about the incidents in the form of structured individual and group discussions and help the persons affected regain their ability to apply coping strategies. Most of the time these discussions are performed by colleagues who have qualified in CISM programmes (the so-called CISM peer diffusers or CISM peers) or by Mental Health Professionals (MHPs) who are qualified CISM experts. None of the CISM techniques can, or should be, regarded as psycho-therapeutic measures.

Read more at skybrary: https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Critical_Incident_Stress_Management_in_ATM